# How are they different: foxy and foxy-release branches

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am about to check out the source of ros2 foxy, using this command `vcs import src < ros2.repos`.  The file `ros.repos` is here `https://github.com/ros2/ros2/blob/master/ros2.repos`.

The GitHub repository has a branch called `foxy-release`, and another branch called `foxy`. How are they different and which branch should be used?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371996/how-are-they-different:-foxy-and-foxy-release-branches/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-17**:
It was only a comment, but I believe this was discussed in #q371016 as well:

> If you replace `eloquent-release` with `eloquent`, you'd get the state of the branches targetting Eloquent in those repositories, which is potentially different from the packages released into Eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to checkout the source code for Foxy, you should use the `ros2.repos` file from the `foxy` branch. This is the branch referenced by the ["install from source" instructions for Foxy](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Development-Setup/). It will give you the latest development for Foxy.

The `master` branch is always used for the next upcoming release (currently Galactic), and is not compatible with Foxy.

The `foxy-release` branch using git tags for each source repository, representing what we call a "patch release". This is a more formal release, representing a snapshot of all the core packages that we used to produce binaries for all platforms (e.g. archives for Windows, macOS, and Linux).

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2021-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-18**:
From a user perspective, the "source code for Foxy" will typically be understood to mean

> the code used to build the packages I install when running `apt install ros-foxy-...`.

That's different from "the current state of development of Foxy", which is what the `foxy` branch gets you.

With that in mind, it might be clearer to just say:

> `$ROS_DISTRO-release` contains/points to the code used to build the binary packages for each Foxy release. The `$ROS_DISTRO` branches are the development branches, which may have already changed from what was released during the last release.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2021-02-18**:
Unfortunately, it's not completely true that the `$ROS_DISTRO-release` branch points to the code used for all binary packages. Strictly speaking it points to the code that is used to produce "patch release" tarballs. If the user is installing from debs on Ubuntu, then they are getting whatever version of was most recently bloomed (and synced).

Typically, if a user wants to build Foxy from source, they are wanting to make changes to the code (and hopefully contribute back!). Or maybe they're trying to get a recent patch that hasn't been released yet. So, I would recommend working with the latest set of fixes. If you are not planning to change code, then I'd recommend installing the binaries instead.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-18**:\

> Unfortunately, it's not completely true that the `$ROS_DISTRO-release` branch points to the code used for all binary packages. Strictly speaking it points to the code that is used to produce "patch release" tarballs.

that is certainly *unfortunately*.

Is this documented somewhere?

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2021-02-18**:
I thought so, but couldn't find it. We could probably document this caveat on this page: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Maintaining-a-Source-Checkout/#release-versions

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2021-02-18**:
I've proposed adding a note to the docs: https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/1120